# Check data from ArcPad

Tags: arcpad

I cannot check in data from ArcPad. The reason is because in the ArcPad the gdb file does not appear. Only the map file appears and it is not recognized with the gdb file that is in ArcGIS.

Is there a way to convert to convert the amp file to a shapefile or a feature class?

I am using ArcPad for data collection. When a new feature or polygon is created in the field and checked in the database the polygon appears good. When we go out again and do more data collection and create other new polygons and check the data again all the new polygons will appears plus the ones done the previous week and appear as duplicate. I don't know why this is happening and I have to go one by one deleting them because it gives me and extra acreage.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

A few key points:

- You can't use .gdb files in ArcPad. ArcPad uses a mobile database with the suffix .axf
- The only way you can only drag-and-drop your files from ArcPad into ArcMap is you have been collecting data in shapefile format. In this case, you will have the shapefile in your project folder.
- The .apm file is the ArcPad Map Document - like how a .mxd is in ArcMap. It does not contain your data.

If you used the ArcPad Data Manager Toolbar to check out your data from an existing geodatabase, you will need to use it to check your data back in as well. Copy your project folder from your device onto your desktop. In ArcMap, select the 'Get Data From ArcPad' tool from the ArcPad Data Manager Toolbar. Browse to the location of your project folder on your desktop. Select the .axf file in the project folder. Review your edits and check the changes back into your geodatabase. Please make sure that you are using the same geodatabase for both operations and do not attempt to move or rename the .gdb in between check-out and check-in.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcpad/10.2/app/index.html#/What_is_the_ArcPad_Data_Manager_for_ArcGIS/00s10000007t000000/

Answer (score 1):

With ArcPad once you Check In your field data from ArcPad to ArcGIS using the ArcPad Data Manager you MUST check out the data from ArcGIS, again using ArcPad Data Manager, and transfer the checked out data back to your ArcPad system.

If you don't do this but keep gong out and collecting more data with ArcPad without updating the database you will keep duplicating your field data every time you check the data back into ArcGIS.